# Overlaying two fading circles using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

I have the following MWE which draws two fading filled circles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[inner color=red,outer color=white] (0,0) circle (1.8);
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\fill[inner color=red,outer color=white] (0,0) circle (1.8);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to change the scope `xshift` to 3cm. The problem is that the circles overlap with the right circle placed on top of that on the left circle. I want the colour intensity to instead add constructively.

A seperate question: How can I add a Gaussian function on top of the circles without the axes? The examples I saw on the TikZ site used the pgfplots package which draws the axes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use the `fadings` library (search the `\tikzfading` documentation in the PGF/TikZ manual.)

### The output

[image]
I think it did not look very pretty with both red disks, so I changed one to blue.

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading %strangely gives bad bounding box when inside the tikzpicture
[
  name=fade out,
  inner color=transparent!0,
  outer color=transparent!100
]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset
  {
    myCircle/.style=
    {
      red,
      path fading=fade out,
    }
  }
  \def\a{1}
  \fill[myCircle] (-\a,0) circle (1.8);
  \fill[myCircle, blue,] (\a,0) circle (1.8);
  \draw plot [samples=200] (\x, {exp(-.5*(\x)^2)}) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Marsupilam, thanks! The bounding box can be sorted by moving the `\tikzfading` and `\tikzset` commands outside of the `\tikzpicture` enviroment.

Comment: Thank you. It is enough to take the `tikzfading` out. I'll edit.

Comment: I had a problem where my standalone figures in a beamer presentation were moving in unexpected ways when using fadings. Putting `\tikzfading` outside of the `\tikzpicture` solved it. Do you know whether this is documented somewhere (I could not immediately find it in the tikz manual)?

Answer (score 2):

I am a little uncertain of how it works, but I think you need `Fadings` from the TikZ manual section 23.4. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\tikzfading[name=fade inside,
inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!30] 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[ball color=red,path fading=fade inside] (0,0) circle (1.8);
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\shade[ball color=red,path fading=fade inside] (0,0) circle (1.8);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Balls with fadings]